# How to use join operation in rails to get desired result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

I am new to Ruby-on-Rails
I have following tables with below mentioned attributes

Supplier - id ,name,address etc------

Variant - id ,price,etc---

SupplierVariant- supplier_id,variant_id

LineItem - variant_id ,order_id

There is one more table called 'Order' which has line_items as it attribute.Each 'Order' object is linked to variant through lineitems.My requirement is to get all the supplier_ids from a particular order using the join operation between the tables.

I am using 'Spree' to build my application and for the above mentioned question I have tried the following in rails console

```
ord=Spree::Order.find_by_number("R1218823")

var=ord.line_items.joins(:variant)
```

till here it's working fine, but when I do `var.joins(:SupplierVariant)`, I am getting error.

Comment: pleae paste the error also........

Comment: `var.joins(:SupplierVariant)` should be like this `var.joins(:supplier_variants)` where `:supplier_varients` is the name of the association defined in the `Variant` model

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to pass snake cased name of class.

```
order.line_items.joins(:variants => [ { :supplier_varients => :suppliers }])
```